# C++ Error while doing overloading operators, underfined

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, operators

I get this error

```
myDate.cpp:(.text+0x160): undefined reference to `myTime::operator==(myTime const&) const'
```

It is my first time coding with header files and overloading operators so any help would be greatly appreciated. This is my code for myDate: http://pastebin.com/i4CLvWBS the Header: http://pastebin.com/ULircg5q

Where the errors are coming from `theTime==date.getTime());`

And here is an example of my overloaded operator

```
bool myDate::operator==(const myDate &date) const
{
  return (year == date.getYear() && 
          month==date.getMonth() && 
          day==date.getDay() && 
          theTime==date.getTime());
}
```

the time is from a different file called myTime and I have no clue how to properly define the operator and just in case you would new myTime to help me solve this problem : vWr5zwDq just follow that up in pastebin

I also made sure that myTime.cpp was linked properly because myTime.cpp is linked to myTime.h which is linked to myDate.h and myDate.h is linked to myTime.cpp and when I remover `#include "myTime.h"` from my myDate.h my code broke for that file.

```
#include "myTime.h"  #include "myTime.h"   #include "myDate.h"
myTime::myTime()     class myDate()        myDate::myDate()
```

Comment: Remove from the header record #include "myTime.h".

Comment: _"... because myTime.cpp is linked to myTime.h which is linked to myDate.h and myDate.h ..."_ What kind of nonsense is this?

Comment: Did you mean you have proper `#include` statements for all headers needed? That's not what's meant with _linking_.

Comment: Yes that is what I thought you meant, but I'm reading that article you showed me now. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare/define an appropriate `bool operator==(myTime const&) const;` for your class `myTime` as well.

If you did so, make sure that `myTime.cpp` is linked with the rest of the code properly.

See here for more in depth information about this error message and what *linking* actually means:
**[What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)**